# centos8 install azkaban Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'

Tags: java, mysql-connector, azkaban

environment:
  CentOS8
  mysql  Ver 8.0.17
  java version "1.8.0_261"
  azkaban v3.90.0.

when I try to installing Azkaban Executor Server

```
cd /home/azkaban/azkaban/azkaban-exec-server/build/distributions
tar -xzvf azkaban-exec-server-3.91.0-4-gb468bffe.tar.gz

cd /home/azkaban/azkaban/azkaban-exec-server/build/distributions/azkaban-exec-server-3.91.0-4-gb468bffe/conf
cp azkaban.properties azkaban.properties_bak20200724
vi azkaban.properties
mysql.database=azkaban
mysql.user=azkaban
mysql.password=azkabanpassword
```

Then run:

```
cd /home/azkaban/azkaban/azkaban-exec-server/build/distributions/azkaban-exec-server-3.91.0-4-gb468bffe
./bin/start-exec.sh
```

in executorServerLog__2020-07-24+17:59:49.out

```
ERROR [MySQLDataSource] [main] [Azkaban] Failed to find write-enabled DB connection. Wait 15 seconds and retry. No.Attempt = 2
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot create PoolableConnectionFactory (Could not create connection to database server.)
```

So I download mysql-connector-java-8.0.17.jar and put this jar into '/home/azkaban/azkaban/azkaban-exec-server/build/distributions/azkaban-exec-server-3.91.0-4-gb468bffe/lib'

when I try to start again,also fails:

```
ERROR [StdOutErrRedirect] [main] [Azkaban] Loading class `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver'. 
This is deprecated. The new driver class is `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver'. 
The driver is automatically registered via the SPI and manual loading of the driver class is generally unnecessary.
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0):

downgrade mysql from 8.0.17 to mysql5.7.31 resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the  Code:
`com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` in the 51th row of code

```
azkaban/akaban-db/src/main/java/azkaban/db/MySQLDataSource.java
```

to

```
com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
```

**Rebuild**